# how to collect data after window operation? GroupBy messes up the order and I get incorrect results

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have this code

```
groupedDF.show()
val window =
      Window.partitionBy($"app_id", $"country_code").orderBy($"rate".desc)

    val windowResult = groupedDF
      .transform(calculateRankOverWindow(window))
      .limit(topN) //change this to .where("rank<=topN") and it works.

    windowResult.show()
    val finalResult = windowResult
      .groupBy("app_id", "country_code")
      .agg(collect_list("advertiser_id").as("recommended_advertiser_ids"))

    finalResult.show()
```

Sample output of just one app_id and country. as There are many different app_ids and countries.

GrouedDF

```
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|app_id|country_code|advertiser_id|             rate|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
|    32|          UK|            9|              8.0|
|    32|          UK|            5|              5.5|
|    32|          UK|            4|              5.5|
|    32|          UK|            6|              6.1|
|    32|          UK|            3|              5.5|
|    32|          UK|            2|              2.0|
|    32|          UK|            1|6.099999999999999|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

windowResult

```
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
|app_id|country_code|advertiser_id|             rate|rank|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
|    32|          UK|            9|              8.0|   1|
|    32|          UK|            6|              6.1|   2|
|    32|          UK|            1|6.099999999999999|   3|
|    32|          UK|            5|              5.5|   4|
|    32|          UK|            4|              5.5|   4|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+
```

Desired Output format a list of advertiser_ids per app_id and country_code.

Incorrect(What I get)

```
+------+------------+--------------------------+
|app_id|country_code|recommended_advertiser_ids|
+------+------------+--------------------------+
|    32|          UK|           [9, 5, 4, 6, 3]|
+------+------------+--------------------------+
```

Correct(what I want)

```
+------+------------+--------------------------+
|app_id|country_code|recommended_advertiser_ids|
+------+------------+--------------------------+
|    32|          UK|           [9, 6, 1, 5, 4]|
+------+------------+--------------------------+
```

But when I do groupby and collect the groupby messes the order or previous window operation and hence I collect the list [9,5,4,6,3] instead of [9,6,1,5,4].

How can I do it?

If I do

```
windowResult
      .withColumn(
        "recommended_advertiser_ids",
        collect_list("advertiser_id").over(window)
      )
      .show()
```

it gives

```
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------------------------+
|app_id|country_code|advertiser_id|             rate|rank|recommended_advertiser_ids|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------------------------+
|    32|          UK|            9|              8.0|   1|                       [9]|
|    32|          UK|            6|              6.1|   2|                    [9, 6]|
|    32|          UK|            1|6.099999999999999|   3|                 [9, 6, 1]|
|    32|          UK|            5|              5.5|   4|           [9, 6, 1, 5, 4]|
|    32|          UK|            4|              5.5|   4|           [9, 6, 1, 5, 4]|
+------+------------+-------------+-----------------+----+--------------------------+
```

but I just want the last one per group(app_id, country_code).

**UPDATE:** I fixed it by reverting to my original code. i.e.
switched back to `df.where(rank<=n) instead of limit(n)`
But I the reason I switched is rank<=n can give more than n results if the column has same values. So the question is how to pick top n from rank(topN per group)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the original question was.
just replace `limit(n) with df.where("rank<=${n}")`. The issue with that was how I was calculating the rank. I used window rank() function which can give the same rank for the same values. So I was getting more than n values in the answer.

The answer to the updated question: how to get n values is to use another window function row_number() which gives increasing row_numbers based on the window.

So changing `limit() to where and rank() to row_number() solved both.`

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark built in **`monotonically_increasing_id`** function then **collect_list** on the **struct** column by sorting on **`monotonically_increasing_id`** column to preserve the order.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
//+------+------------+-------------+
//|app_id|country_code|advertiser_id|
//+------+------------+-------------+
//|    32|          UK|            9|
//|    32|          UK|            6|
//|    32|          UK|            1|
//|    32|          UK|            5|
//|    32|          UK|            4|
//+------+------------+-------------+
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.withColumn("mid",monotonically_increasing_id()).
groupBy("app_id","country_code").  agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct(col("mid"),col("advertiser_id")))).alias("sor")).
selectExpr("app_id","country_code","""transform(sor,x -> x.advertiser_id) as recommended_advertiser_ids""").
show()

//+------+------------+--------------------------+
//|app_id|country_code|recommended_advertiser_ids|
//+------+------------+--------------------------+
//|    32|          UK|           [9, 6, 1, 5, 4]|
//+------+------------+--------------------------+
```

Another approach would be using **`window function`** and filter out only the **`max array size`** .

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val w=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
val df2=df.withColumn("cl",collect_list(col("advertiser_id")).over(w))
val max_size=df2.selectExpr("max(size(cl))").collect()(0)(0).toString.toInt

val cols=Seq("app_id","country_code","cl")
df2.filter(size(col("cl"))===max_size).
select(cols.head,cols.tail:_*).
show()
//+------+------------+---------------+
//|app_id|country_code|             cl|
//+------+------------+---------------+
//|    32|          UK|[9, 6, 1, 5, 4]|
//+------+------------+---------------+
```

Comment: strage, its giving wrong results. same like mine. The transformations(group/agg) is being applied on grouped data and not the one after window function.

Comment: The increasing_ids are assigned properly at first but they change after groupby or agg(sort) in the first approach which results into output  [9, 5, 4, 6, 3]. which means the transformation is applied on result on groupedDf and not window.

Comment: both approaches give the same incorrect result [9, 5, 4, 6, 3]. I and I don't think the second one would work with multiple app_ids and country_code as there's no grouping. and its just collecting over the hardcoded 5-row dataset.